# Access nodes of xml in right order

Tags: ruby, xml

I have problems to extract data from an xml file:

```
         <diagnosis_list>
            <diagnosis>
              <icd_code V="A00.-"/>
              <description V="Cholera"/>

              <diagnosis_list>

                <diagnosis>
                  <icd_code V="A00.0"/>
                  <description V="Cholera durch Vibrio cholerae O:1, Biovar cholerae"/>
                  <dangerous V="j"/>
                  <subcategories_list>
                    <subcategory V="Klassische Cholera"/>
                  </subcategories_list>
                </diagnosis>

                <diagnosis>
                  <icd_code V="A00.1"/>
                  <description V="Cholera durch Vibrio cholerae O:1, Biovar eltor"/>
                  <dangerous V="j"/>
                  <subcategories_list>
                    <subcategory V="El-Tor-Cholera"/>
                    <subcategory V="Choleraartige Dysenterie"/>
                    <subcategory V="El-Tor-Enteritis"/>
                  </subcategories_list>
                </diagnosis>

              </diagnosis_list>

            </diagnosis>
          </diagnosis_list>
```

I tried several things with nokigiri and Css, but had not really success.
As output i would like something like:

```
 A00.- => Cholera

 A00.0 => Cholera durch Vibrio cholerae O:1, Biovar cholerae
 Subcategories => Klassische Cholera

 A00.1 => Cholera durch Vibrio cholerae O:1, Biovar eltor
 Subcategories => El-Tor-Cholera
                  Choleraartige Dysenterie
                  El-Tor-Enteritis
```

But the output for now is not so important, im happy about every suggestion how to access the nodes of the xml in the right order! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using xpath:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
doc.xpath('//icd_code|//description').each do |node|
  p node['V']
end
```

prints

```
"A00.-"
"Cholera"
"A00.0"
"Cholera durch Vibrio cholerae O:1, Biovar cholerae"
"A00.1"
"Cholera durch Vibrio cholerae O:1, Biovar eltor"
```

---

**UPDATE**

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
doc.css('icd_code').each do |icd_code|
  desc = icd_code.css('~ description')[0]
  puts "#{icd_code['V']} => #{desc['V']}"
  icd_code.css('~ subcategories_list>subcategory').each do |subcategory|
    puts "    #{subcategory['V']}"
  end
end
```

prints

```
A00.- => Cholera
A00.0 => Cholera durch Vibrio cholerae O:1, Biovar cholerae
    Klassische Cholera
A00.1 => Cholera durch Vibrio cholerae O:1, Biovar eltor
    El-Tor-Cholera
    Choleraartige Dysenterie
    El-Tor-Enteritis
```

Comment: Thank you, you really helped me a lot, but how can i retrieve the subcategories from the xml file?

Comment: @JohnSmith, Ah, I missed subcategories.. I added another code.

Comment: I have a new question that belongs to that issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18186566/how-to-parse-data-of-next-node-in-xml-file