# How to Parse data of next node in xml file

Tags: ruby, xml

I try to parse this xml-file, the problem is that i somehow cant get the data of the node "gruppe".

```
 <nummer V="1"/>
      <von_icd_code V="A00"/>
      <bis_icd_code V="B99"/>
      <bezeichnung V="Bestimmte infektiöse und parasitäre Krankheiten"/>
      <gruppen_liste>
        <gruppe>
          <von_icd_code V="A00"/>
          <bis_icd_code V="A09"/>
          <bezeichnung V="Infektiöse Darmkrankheiten"/>
```

My code:

```
 doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("icd2.xml"))

 doc.css('nummer').each do |kapitel|
   desc = kapitel.css('~ von_icd_code')[0]
   desc2 = kapitel.css('~ bis_icd_code')[0]
   desc3 = kapitel.css('~ bezeichnung')[0]
   puts "#{desc['V']} #{desc2['V']} => #{desc3['V']}"

   kapitel.css('~ gruppe').each do |gruppe|
    asc = gruppe.node_name
    puts "    #{asc}"

 end
end
```

Generates this output:

```
 A00 B99 => Bestimmte infektiöse und parasitäre Krankheiten
```

But why generates this code piece no output?

```
 kapitel.css('~ gruppe').each do |gruppe|
    asc = gruppe.node_name
    puts "    #{asc}"

 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following instead:

```
kapitel.css('~ gruppen_liste>gruppe').each do |gruppe|
  asc = gruppe.node_name
  puts "    #{asc}"
end
```

`~ x` matched sibling `x`-tag nodes.

Comment: Sorry but i have a new question to this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187104/xml-access-next-node