# Xml access next node

Tags: ruby, xml

From my xml file i can retrieve the data from the node "gruppe" but somehow i cannot access the node "diagnose"

```
  <gruppen_liste>
        <gruppe>
          <von_icd_code V="A00"/>
          <bis_icd_code V="A09"/>
          <bezeichnung V="Infektiöse Darmkrankheiten"/>
          <diagnosen_liste>
            <diagnose>
              <icd_code V="A00.-"/>
              <bezeichnung V="Cholera"/>
              <abrechenbar V="n"/>
              <krankheit_in_mitteleuropa_sehr_selten V="j"/>
              <schlüsselnummer_mit_inhalt_belegt V="j"/>
              <infektionsschutzgesetz_meldepflicht V="j"/>
              <infektionsschutzgesetz_abrechnungsbesonderheit V="j"/>
              <diagnosen_liste>
                <diagnose>
```

My code:

```
kapitel.css('~ gruppen_liste>gruppe').each do |gruppe|
asc = gruppe.css('von_icd_code')[0]
asc2 = gruppe.css('von_icd_code')[0]
asc3 = gruppe.css('bezeichnung')[0]
puts "  #{asc['V']} #{asc2['V']} => #{asc3['V']}"

 gruppe.css('~ diagnosen_liste>diagnose').each do |diagnose|
    cesc = diagnose.css('icd_code')[0]
    puts "     #{cesc['V']}"
 end
end
```

But somehow it only generates this output:

```
 A00 A09 => Infektiöse Darmkrankheiten
```

Why generates this code no output?

```
 gruppe.css('~ diagnosen_liste>diagnose').each do |diagnose|
    cesc = diagnose.css('~ icd_code')[0]
    puts "     #{cesc['V']}"
 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `~ diagnosen_liste>diagnose`, the `~` is a general sibling selector. This means that the `diagnosen_liste` node has to be a sibling of the `gruppe` node. Given that `diagnosen_liste` is a child rather than a sibling, nothing is found.

Try removing the tilde:

```
gruppe.css('diagnosen_liste>diagnose').each do |diagnose|
  cesc = diagnose.css('~ icd_code')[0]
  puts "     #{cesc['V']}"
end
```